# Have information bits a mass-energy equivalence?

Tags: cosmology, mass-energy, dark-matter, information, dark-energy

Is it plausible (as some authors conjectured recently) that information is physical and that information bits are stored as a mass-energy equivalent in the universe, accounting for cosmic dark energy and dark matter?

Comment: It would be useful to cite what authors and papers you're referring to.  Right now it's difficult to answer given the lack of context

Comment: The authors cited are Melvin M. Vopson and M. P. Gough. You can google for their recent papers.

Comment: If you want people to help you need to be make more effort in editing in necessary information.  Expecting people to google papers and read them to find the information is going to put people off.

Comment: Related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landauers-principle

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=+vopson

Answer (score 1):

Glancing at the paper

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333751969_The_information_content_of_the_Universe_and_the_implications_for_the_missing_Dark_Matter

from a holistic standpoint, and without digging into the physics much, my opinion is it seems far fetched, and also the "simple experiment" he proposes involves measuring the change in mass in a 1 Tb hard drive to the level of a few hundred protons.  Not a serious suggestion.

If the extra gravity attributed to dark matter were really caused by "information content" in ordinary matter, one would expect that "information matter" to have roughly the same spatial distribution as the ordinary matter. I.e. regular matter would just be "heavier."  What we actually observe in galaxies is Dark Matter Halos, relatively spherical distributions of dark matter alongside planar disks of ordinary matter. In addition, if orindary matter were "heavier" due to information content, we would expect to see that at all scales – e.g. the Sun and the Earth and a bowling ball would weigh more than our knowledge of the weights of the molecules that make it up would predict. None of this is true.

Finally, dark energy is a repulsive (roughly speaking) rather than an attractive force, so could not be explained by heavier matter in any case.